# Find the smallest integer whose sum of squares of digits add to the given number

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

**Example:**

Input:  |  Output:

- 5 –> 12 (1^2 + 2^2 = 5)
- 500 -> 18888999 (1^2 + 8^2 + 8^2 + 8^2 + 9^2 + 9^2 + 9^2 = 500)

I have written a pretty simple brute-force solution, but it has big performance problems:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 int n;
 bool found = true;
 unsigned long int sum = 0;

 cin >> n;
 int i = 0;
 while (found) {
     ++i;
     if (n == 0) { //The code below doesn't work if n = 0, so we assign value to sum right away (in case n = 0)
         sum = 0;
         break;
     }
     int j = i;
     while (j != 0) { //After each iteration, j's last digit gets stripped away (j /= 10), so we want to stop right when j becomes 0
         sum += (j % 10) * (j % 10); //After each iteration, sum gets increased by *(last digit of j)^2*. (j % 10) gets the last digit of j
         j /= 10;
     }
     if (sum == n) { //If we meet our problem's requirements, so that sum of j's each digit squared is equal to the given number n, loop breaks and we get our result
        break;
     }
     sum = 0; //Otherwise, sum gets nullified and the loops starts over
 }

 cout << i;

 return 0;
 }
```

I am looking for a fast solution to the problem.

Comment: You problem is not well posed. For example you can say `any number -> 1111111...1111`. Which would be a trivial yet correct, and yet efficient, solution. I think you have to go back to formulation stage.

Comment: The problem states "find the **smallest** integer whose sum of squares of digits add to the given number"

Comment: My bad, you are right! This question is much more interesting than it looks like and probably should be better valorized. I would suggest to state the problem completely in the body of the question rather than relying on the question title.

Comment: After quickly resolving 123999999 i have come to the awareness of the fact that this is in fact a very cool question.

Comment: It is very hard to understand the rationale of your implementation. Can you add explanations and/or make the code more understandable?

Comment: My rationale would be to divide `n` by `81`, to obtain the number of `9`'s. Then take the remander, divide it by `64`, which is the number of `8`'s, and so on...

Comment: Note that all permutations of the digits in the result have the same property. Thus, one possible solution could be to find the smallest collection of perfect squares <= 81 that sum to the input. Also note that the smallest number with The Property for 419 is 1888899 (and so on). This suggests that dynamic programming could be the way forward.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon That would give a wrong answer for e.g. 89. Best answer is 64+25 -> 58. Your algorithm would yield 81+4+4 -> 229.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use dynamic programming. If we knew the first digit of the optimal solution, then the rest would be an optimal solution for the remainder of the sum. As a result, we can guess the first digit and use a cached computation for smaller targets to get the optimum.

```
def digitsum(n):
    best = [0]
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        best.append(min(int(str(d) + str(best[i - d**2]).strip('0'))
                        for d in range(1, 10)
                        if i >= d**2))
    return best[n]
```

Comment: I just started out competitive programming, so dynamic programming is a topic yet to be discovered for me. Could you add some explanations to code so it can be less abstruse and more understandable? Thanks a lot

Comment: @RafaelSofi-Zadeh There's a lot of tutorial material out there. Maybe you should start with that.

Comment: @Rafael Sofi-Zadeh I  would advise you [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Collection-Dynamic-Programming-Interview-Questions/dp/1495320480) I am sure it will quickly give you an idea about dynamical programming.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try and explain David's solution. I believe his assumption is that given an optimal solution, `abcd...`, the optimal solution for `n - a^2` would be `bcd...`, therefore if we compute all the solutions from `1` to `n`, we can rely on previous solutions for numbers smaller than `n` as we try different subtractions.

So how can we interpret David's code?

(1) Place the solutions for the numbers 1 through `n`, in order, in the table `best`:

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
    best.append(...
```

(2) the solution for the current query, `i`, is the minimum in an array of choices for different digits, `d`, between `1` and `9` if subtracting `d^2` from `i` is feasible.

The minimum of the conversion to integers...

```
min(int(
```

...of the the string, `d`, concatenated with the string of the solution for `n - d^2` previously recorded in the table (removing the concatenation of the solution for zero):

```
        str(d) + str(best[i - d**2]).strip('0')
```

Let's modify the last line of David's code, to see an example of how the table works:

```
def digitsum(n):
    best = [0]
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        best.append(min(int(str(d) + str(best[i - d**2]).strip('0'))
                        for d in range(1, 10)
                        if i >= d**2))

    return best # original line was 'return best[n]'
```

We call, `digitsum(10)`:

```
=> [0, 1, 11, 111, 2, 12, 112, 1112, 22, 3, 13]
```

When we get to `i = 5`, our choices for `d` are `1` and `2` so the array of choices is:

```
   min([ int(str(1) + str(best[5 - 1])), int(str(2) + str(best[5 - 4])) ])
=> min([ int(   '1'   +     '2'       ), int(   '2'   +     '1'      ) ])
```

And so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

So this is in fact a well known problem in disguise. [The minimum coin change problem](http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/dynamic-programming-minimum-coin-change-problem/) in which you are given a sum and requested to pay with minimum number of coins. Here instead of ones, nickels, dimes and quarters we have 81, 64, 49, 36, ... , 1 cents.

Apparently this is a typical example to encourage dynamic programming. In dynamic programming, unlike in recursive approach in which you are expected to go from top to bottom, you are now expected to go from bottom to up and "memoize" the results those will be required later. Thus... much faster..!

So ok here is my approach in JS. It's probably doing a very similar job to David's method.

```js
function getMinNumber(n){
  var sls = Array(n).fill(),
      sct = [], max;
  sls.map((_,i,a) => { max = Math.min(9,~~Math.sqrt(i+1)),
                       sct = [];
                       while (max) sct.push(a[i-max*max] ? a[i-max*max].concat(max--)
                                                         : [max--]);
                       a[i] = sct.reduce((p,c) => p.length < c.length ? p : c);
                     });
  return sls[sls.length-1].reverse().join("");
}
console.log(getMinNumber(500));
```

What we are doing is from bottom to up generating a look up array called `sls`. This is where memoizing happens. Then starting from from `1` to `n` we are mapping the best result among several choices. For example if we are to look for `10`'s partitions we will start with the integer part of 10's square root which is 3 and keep it in the `max` variable. So 3 being one of the numbers the other should be 10-3*3 = 1. Then we look up for the previously solved `1` which is in fact `[1]` at `sls[0]` and concat 3 to `sls[0]`. And the result is `[3,1]`. Once we finish with 3 then one by one we start over the same job with one smaller, up until it's 1. So after 3 we check for 2 (result is `[2,2,1,1]`) and then for 1 (result is `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`) and compare the length of the results of 3, 2 and 1 for the shortest, which is `[3,1]` and store it at `sls[9]` (a.k.a `a[i]`) which is the place for 10 in our look up array.

Answer (score 0):

**(Edit) This answer is not correct. The greedy approach does not work for this problem -- sorry.**

I'll give my solution in a language agnostic fashion, i.e. the algorithm.
I haven't tested but I believe this should do the trick, and the complexity is proportional to the number of digits in the output:

```
   digitSquared(n) {

      % compute the occurrences of each digit
      numberOfDigits = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
      for m from 9 to 1 {

        numberOfDigits[m] = n / m*m;
        n = n % m*m;
          if (n==0)
            exit loop;
      }

     % assemble the final output
     output = 0
     powerOfTen = 0
     for m from 9 to 1 {
       for i from 0 to numberOfDigits[m] {
         output = output + m*10^powerOfTen
         powerOfTen = powerOfTen + 1
       }
     }

   }
```

Comment: This would give a wrong answer for e.g. 89. Best answer is 64+25 -> 58. Your algorithm would yield 81+4+4 -> 229.